# Configuring/using Drupal Pathauto module

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I am new to Drupal. I just installed Drupal 8 and [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

Now I need to configure `path patterns` or whatever they are called.

On page https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/pathauto they give the path for configuring as:

For 7.x, 8.x: **Administer** > **Configuration** > **Search and Metadata** > **URL aliases**, in the "**Patterns**" tab.

But can't see "Patterns" tab. When I click http://localhost/admin/config/search/path/add I get to a page with a form and 2 fields:
1. Existing system path
2. Path alias

I also tried http://localhost/admin/config/search/path/pathauto and http://localhost/admin/config/search/pathauto but they both give me 'Page not found'.

How do I configure `Pathauto`?

Comment: You wrote that you installed the module but have you enabled it? That is a separate step, if by "installing" you mean "downloaded the files".

Comment: @cilefen, I had not enabled it. Let me enable it then I will update. Thanks.

Comment: @cilefen I got it running now. Let me play around with it. In case of any question (s) I will update. Thanks a lot for helping on this.

Comment: @cilefen I just created a simple pattern [current-page:title].html but not getting desired result. Basically I need URL to be page tile with .html access. e.g. an article titles 'Rio Olympics' should give rio-olympcs.html. When I created sample article I got create-article.html as URL, which means Pathauto is interpreting the pattern differently. Any idea?

Comment: @cilefen I finally got it. The correct pattern is [node:title].html. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module must be [enabled and configured](https://www.drupal.org/node/895232) after installing its files.